# With 64kbps upload speed, is it worth buying a 720p webcam?

Tags: webcam

I am going to buy me an webcam for the purpose of instant video chatting over the internet.

It is worth noticing that I am using a ADSL network with only 64kbps upload per sec. So I am really worrying that I can afford an webcam of 720p quality. Even if they can use a lower resolution, it is a waste of money to use such webcams.

EDIT: I suspect that I am not having a upload speed of 64kbps, but 64kB/s which translates to 512kbps, please check this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/347138/how-do-i-know-my-true-upload-speed) that I asked. Thanks.

Is my network speed even okay for VGA output?

Comment: I think it can be answered, just removed the specific models in question.

Comment: Thanks dude. I include the specs only because I want to be informative. I never know it is so violating the rule.

Comment: No worries. The models gave an impression of just asking for shopping rec, that's why it's a bit problematic. Which software are you going to use?

Comment: I don't know. I want to get some freelance from odesk and I assume most     
employer would like to do the interview online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like 64kbps is not enough to have any kind of decent video chat, and 720p webcam will be a total waste.

For example, [Skype FAQ says](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1417/How-much-bandwidth-does-Skype-need) that:

```
Call type         Minimum download/upload speed   Recommended download/upload speed
Calling           30kbps / 30kbps                 100kbps / 100kbps
Video calling /
Screen sharing    128kbps / 128kbps               300kbps / 300kbps
Video calling
(high-quality)    400kbps / 400kbps               500kbps / 500kbps
Video calling
(HD)              1.2Mbps / 1.2Mbps               1.5Mbps / 1.5Mbps
```

Skype is pretty efficient with video compression, and other software's bandwidth requirements will be similar. While you might be able to use video chat per se, it seems to me 720p bandwidth requirements are way too high for you.

Comment: Which category does VGA falls into?

Comment: Depends on the compression and the framerate. Either "Video Calling" or "Video calling (high quality)". Both can be 640x480, but the quality will be vastly different. Video Calling (HD) is 720p.

Comment: Can you check me edit and help to check if I am suitable for VGA?

Comment: Yeah your 512kbps ADSL is suitable for good quality VGA, but still no go for 720p HD. However, HD cameras are better quality in general, so it's up to you... If you plan to upgrade your ADSL in the future, that HD camera might come handy then.