# How do I know my true upload speed?

Tags: home-networking

I always think my upload speed is 64KB/s because that is the maximum upload rate per sec I can get in emule. I am using ADSL.

But I just run a speed test through speedtest.net. It said I have an upload speed of 0.52 Mbps, then how to explan what happens in emule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The unit `B` represents bytes while `b` represents bits. There are 8 bits in a byte. The readings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case of traffic shaping or some such by your ISP. In general this is where the ISP uses some method of determining the type of content you are using and reduces its speed accordingly -- they are generally quite hostile to any form of file sharing activity.

The true speed will be the speed given by speed test, but it may be worth trying a second speed test to be certain.